# my tox setenv PYTHONPATH is not working but sh -c to forcefully set PYTHONPATH works

Tags: python, testing, tox

```
[testenv:migrations]
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/src:{toxinidir}/tests
deps =
    -r requirements/py310-django42.txt
commands =
    echo PYTHONPATH={env:PYTHONPATH:}
    python tests/migration_script.py
    echo PYTHONPATH={env:PYTHONPATH:}
allowlist_externals =
    sh
    echo
```

when i do the above, and i try to print sys.path at the top of migration_script.py I see that the PYTHONPATH isn't set. Same thing with the `echo PYTHONPATH=`.

But when I do `sh -c`

```
setenv =
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/src:{toxinidir}/tests
deps =
    -r requirements/py310-django42.txt
commands_pre =
    sh -c 'export PYTHONPATH={toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/src:{toxinidir}/tests'
commands =
    sh -c 'PYTHONPATH={toxinidir}:{toxinidir}/src:{toxinidir}/tests python tests/migration_script.py'
    # python tests/migration_script.py
    echo PYTHONPATH={env:PYTHONPATH:}
allowlist_externals =
    sh
    echo
```

the sys.path at the top of `migration_script.py` works perfectly.

I am deeply confused why setenv doesn't work.

Please help me to understand why.